# How to do translation dictionary dynamically in logstash based on field value?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

How to do translation dictionary dynamically in logstash based on field value?
For example my current configuration is:

```
if [host] == "1.1.1.1" {
    translate {
        field => "[netflow][input_snmp]"
        destination => "[netflow][interface_in]"
        dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/yaml/1.1.1.1.yml"
    }
} 
if [host] == "2.2.2.2" {
            translate {
                    field => "[netflow][input_snmp]"
                    destination => "[netflow][interface_in]"
                    dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/yaml/2.2.2.2.yml"
            }
}
```

Is there a generic way to achieve this?
Logstash version 2.2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use it as:

```
translate {
    field => "[netflow][input_snmp]"
    destination => "[netflow][interface_in]"
    dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/yaml/%{host}.yml"
}
```

Check that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#sprintf

Comment: It seems I can't use it like this: translate {
      # This setting must be a path
      # File does not exist or cannot be opened /etc/logstash/yaml/%{host}.yml
      dictionary_path => "/etc/logstash/yaml/%{host}.yml"

Comment: The same here, field placeholders seem not to be working in dictionary_path. @alpert Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you tried using "/etc/logstash/yaml/%{[host]}.yml" @sermolaev

Answer (score 0):

You can't load dictionary files dynamically depening on field value, it's not a question of syntax.
At least for the moment (current logstash version is 7.6.2)

All dictionary files are loaded in memory at logstash startup (and I suppose after a logstash configuration reload), before any event is processed.

Then the contents of the existing dictionary files are dynamically reloaded according to the [refresh_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html#plugins-filters-translate-refresh_interval) option.

The dictionary paths can't be modified "at run time" depending on the current event.

In the elastic support forums you can check extra explanation (the 1st link even has a reference to the source code involved) and workarounds, but in the end it revolves around the same idea shown in your config: 
set a bunch of static dictionary file names and control their usage with conditionals. You may use environment variables in the `dictionary_path` but they will be used once per logstash startup/reload.

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dynamic-dictionary/138798/5
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-translate-plugin-dynamic-dictionary-path/129889